# How to count items in a directory?

Tags: android, count, directory, numbers, items

I would need to count number of items in a directory in Android, for example; How many files are there in my "layout" directory?

If I was to count an array I would simply do

```
(int i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++){
    count++;
}
```

How do I change "array.lenght" to something suitable for a directory?
I'm doing this because I want to create X-number of views depending on amount of items in drawable. So if I would add a new ".XML" in the drawable directory, my app would generate another view for that item automatically because of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Android resources are identified by the constants in the R class generated by the aapt. Thanks to reflection you can count number of fields (e.g. the drawables):

```
int getDrawablesCount() {
    return R.drawable.class.getFields().length;
}
```

Comment: Will try that out and return to accept your answer if it works. Thanks!